# Babel unshiftcontainer not creating an element

Tags: javascript, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

Playing around with babel transforms and I've written this snippet to insert a `VariableDeclaration` after my `path`

```js
export default function (babel) {
  const { types: t } = babel;

  return {
    name: "ast-transform", // not required
    visitor: {
      VariableDeclaration (path) {
        if (path.node.kind !== 'var') {
          return;
        }

        const _id = t.Identifier('qwe');
        const _init = t.numericLiteral(42);

        console.log(_id, _init);

        const _node = t.variableDeclaration('var', [
          t.variableDeclarator(
            t.identifier("uid"),
            t.numericLiteral(42)
          )
        ]);

        path
          .unshiftContainer(
            'body',
            _node
          )

      }
    }
  };
}
```

Get the following error,

> unknown: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

**Edit:**

If I do the following instead of `unshiftContainer` it works,

```
const _program = path.findParent(p => p.isProgram());
_program.node.body.unshift(_node);
```

Why doesn't `unshiftContainer` work?

Link to gist on [ast-explorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/3f04d1c1f5d80f9b34359e7e5dc5d19a/bb19b67135d959ecd3417a5e6df269b4ef1ec3af)

Comment: Have you tried to remove `.get('body')` as in the [docs example](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration-api#babel-traverse)?.. just guessing

Comment: BTW, you're logging `t.Identifier` and then using `t.identifier` (different casing), maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @MaximMazurok - yeah removing it shows "unknown: cannot read property '0' of undefined" - I'll debug to see what I can find there.

Also, updating the casing didn't help.

Comment: @MaximMazurok I've updated my question with an alternate method that works; question still remains as to why `unshiftContainer` doesn't work.

Comment: I've added an answer, hope that explains everything. It was fun to debug :)

Comment: @MaximMazurok - thanks for the answer, I get an infinite loop error when I do `_program.unshiftContainer("body", _node)` in astexplorer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use `unshiftContainer("body")` you have to have a node with "body". For example, `Program` or `FunctionDeclaration` ([1](https://github.com/danez/babel-babylon/blob/69f7ef6b36f8c72dbcf1e3dcd8645433de32bb79/packages/babel-traverse/test/modification.js#L42), [2](https://github.com/gguimond/babel-plugin-source-map-support/blob/71c37d5db86c7a3a220bf15656b9f94f793be1d8/src/index.js), [3](https://github.com/ProcrasTech/picklescript/blob/cb191364c4a007093edcd1cb0f1b2268595eb4b1/src/picklescript.js))

But you were trying to do that on `VariableDeclaration` which doesn't have `body` as you can see in [ast-explorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/3f04d1c1f5d80f9b34359e7e5dc5d19a/bb19b67135d959ecd3417a5e6df269b4ef1ec3af).

When you call `path.get("body")`, it returns `{..., node: undefined, ...}` and then, when you call `unshiftContainer("body")`, it tries to get `"body"` of `node`, which is `undefined`: `container: this.node[listKey],`.

Your solution works because you're finding `Program` object, which has body.
So, this also would work if you want to use `unshiftContainer`:

```js
const _program = path.findParent(p => p.isProgram());
_program.unshiftContainer("body", _node);
```

---

Also, you can do this:

```js
const parentWithBody = path.findParent(
  (p) => p.node !== undefined && p.node.body !== undefined
);
parentWithBody.unshiftContainer("body", _node);
```

It will detect not only `Program`, but also `FunctionDeclaration`:

Source:

```js
var x = 10;
var y = 5;

function test() {
  var z = 1;
}
```

Output:

```js
var uid = 42;
var uid = 42;
var x = 10;
var y = 5;

function test() {
  var uid = 42;
  var z = 1;
}
```

---

**Update** regarding infinite loop,

Indeed, when you unshift container, you're adding new `VariableDeclaration`, so it will go into the infinite loop:

1. see `var x = 10` -> add `var uid = 42`
2. see `var uid = 42` -> add `var uid = 42`
3. and so on...

In order to break this loop, add this condition, where you check if the `node.kind` is `var`:

```js
if (path.node.declarations[0].init.value === 42 && path.node.declarations[0].id.name === "uid") {
  return;
}
```

([gist](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/3f04d1c1f5d80f9b34359e7e5dc5d19a/1344031c22c5ed972b67928f0250c90e532b3810))

Comment: Thanks @Maxim - but the part about being able to use `unshiftContainer` on `_program`, I tried that in astexplorer before posting the question (and even now) I get this error - `unknown: Infinite loop detected on line 14`

Comment: @pai.not.pi sorry for not mentioning this in the initial answer, please, see the update :)

Comment: ohh right! that makes sense now :D - thanks for the update, this was intriguing. PS: need to wait 20hrs before I can award bounty :)

Comment: @pai.not.pi friendly reminder, that 20 hours have passed :)

Comment: Done! There you go!